# Multiple Object variable to numeric?

Tags: python, variables, scikit-learn, numeric

I have a really big dataset in which I have to do a decision tree. For that I need to do the fitting and I can't have object variables. I have like 20 object variables. How can I convert those to numeric?
In python

```
['MachineIdentifier',
 'ProductName',
 'EngineVersion',
 'AppVersion',
 'AvSigVersion',
 'Platform',
 'Processor',
 'OsVer',
 'OsPlatformSubRelease',
 'OsBuildLab',
 'SkuEdition',
 'SmartScreen',
 'Census_MDC2FormFactor',
 'Census_DeviceFamily',
 'Census_ProcessorClass',
 'Census_PrimaryDiskTypeName',
 'Census_ChassisTypeName',
 'Census_PowerPlatformRoleName',
 'Census_InternalBatteryType',
 'Census_OSVersion',
 'Census_OSArchitecture',
 'Census_OSBranch',
 'Census_OSEdition',
 'Census_OSSkuName',
 'Census_OSInstallTypeName',
 'Census_OSWUAutoUpdateOptionsName',
 'Census_GenuineStateName',
 'Census_ActivationChannel',
 'Census_FlightRing']
```

Those are my variables, with different values inside

Comment: You should add your code in order that the community may help you

Comment: P{lease do not use the comments space to provide code - edit & update your question accordingly instead & delete the comment if no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LabelEncoder()`:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
features = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4']
le.fit(features)
new_features = le.transform(features)
```